# DateFormat produces incorrect output

Tags: java, android, date-format

I've got a couple of Buttons that initially display the current date and the current time, respectively. When clicking in the Button that displays the date, it shows a `DatePickerFragment` that allows the user to choose a date, and then changes the Button's text to the date selected by the user. The other Button does exactly the same but with a `TimePickerFragment`.
To initialize the Buttons I use the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
...
df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
tf = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
initDate = new GregorianCalendar();
...
updateDateButtons();
updateTimeButtons();
}
```

```
private void updateTimeButtons() {
    tf.setCalendar(initDate);
    String text = tf.format(initDate.getTime());
    btnIniTime.setText(text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(":")));
}
private void updateDateButtons() {
    df.setCalendar(initDate);
    btnIniDate.setText(df.format(initDate.getTime()));
}
```

Initially, both buttons behave in an expected manner: `btnIniTime` shows the current time, and `btnIniDate` shows the current date.
As I said, when the user clicks the `btnIniTime` button, it shows a `TimePickerFragment` that prompts the user to choose a time, and the selected time is correctly displayed in `btnIniTime`.
The problem starts with `btnIniDate`, that should do the same, but using a `DatePickerFragment` instead of a `TimePickerFragment`. When the user selects a date, the button then displays an incorrect date. For example, if I choose 2013 Aug 30, the displayed date turns to be 2013 Aug. 26. If I choose 2013 Sep 1, it then shows 2013 Sep 29!
The classes and methods that I use to change the date ara arranged in the following way:

```
public abstract static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    protected TaskActivity activity;
    protected Calendar c;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = (TaskActivity) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState);

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        if(activity instanceof TaskActivity){
            setDateResult(year, month, day);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void setDateResult(int year, int month, int day);
}
public static class InitDatePickerFragment extends DatePickerFragment {
    @Override
    protected void setDateResult(int year, int month, int day) {
        activity.setInitDate(year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = activity.getInitDate();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }
}
...
public Calendar getInitDate() {
    return initDate;
}
public void setInitDate(int year, int month, int day){
    Log.d("TaskActivity", "Year: " + year + "; Month: " + month + "; Day: " + day);
    initDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    initDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    initDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
    updateDateButtons();
}
```

When you push the button:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.equals(btnIniDate)){
        DialogFragment newFragment = new InitDatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "initDatePicker");
    }
    ...
}
```

By the way, when setting the date, LogCat produces the following output (I've chosen 2013 Aug 30):

```
Year: 2013; Month: 7; Day:30
```

Comment: Please note that month in given in the form 0-11 and not 1-12.

Comment: I know that. But that's not the problem. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem might be

```
initDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
```

in your `setInitDate()`. This updates only the day of the week. So your date jumps +-6

use

```
initDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
```